# Design Pattern Between Two Object's Interaction

Tags: oop, design-patterns, interaction

I have two objects, ObjectA and ObjectB.  ObjectA needs to call events on ObjectB.  I was looking for a good design pattern to allow ObjectA to do this, because I don't want to expose public methods for anyone to do this, yet ObjectA really needs to do the work of firing those events.

Is there a good pattern for this, or any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Describing the problem more concretely would help us figure out what you really need better.  From what you describe it's just scope.  ObjectB needs access to some of ObjectA's methods that you don't want public.  So they have to be "friends".

Comment: if the language is java or c# you could make those methods have 'package' visibility.

Comment: ObjectA is a provider class, ObjectB is a .NET control.  Rather than make the .NET control really, really large, I use a provider to do the work (ObjectA), but I need to have ObjectA then call events of ObjectB...  I was looking for more of a presentational pattern maybe or something else.

Comment: How provider decides when to call ObjectB events, give an example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ObjectA needs to call events on ObjectB

well the way you describe it sounds like A sending *commands* to B, which makes Command pattern a usual suspect.

Also the way to establish close encounters between A and B may turn out complicated enough to justify establishing a separate object C to *mediate* their interaction - Mediator pattern

Answer (score 3):

If an object needs to call methods from another class, it doesn't really sound like good design to begin with.

Comment: Instances of a class call methods on other class instances all the time...  That's common to OOP...

Comment: You're forgetting that there are many, many poor implementations of OOP.

Comment: Amen to that.  But look at my second comment, as architecture is forcing my design, otherwise I'd have one really, really big control.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  This is usually used when one object needs to receive notification from another object.

[image: UML From Wikipedia]